# Digim card is detecting as Ethernet Controller

Tags: asterisk, telephony

I have a two digium cards in a single machine. 1 is 4 port card. The model number is Wildcard TE420  and another one is single port card. The model number is Wildcard TE121. When i execute the lspci command I got the following output for my digium card.

```
05:08.0 Ethernet controller: Digium, Inc. Device 8000 (rev 11)
07:08.0 Communication controller: Digium, Inc. Device 1420 (rev 02)
```

In the above  "Communication controller" only is correct. Why another card is detecting as Ethernet controller.

The following is my dahdi systems.conf.

```
# Span 1: TE4/0/1 "T4XXP (PCI) Card 0 Span 1" (MASTER)
span=1,1,0,CAS,hdb3
# termtype: te
fxsks=1-15,17-31
dchan=16
echocanceller=mg2,1-15,17-31

# Span 2: TE4/0/2 "T4XXP (PCI) Card 0 Span 2"
span=2,2,0,CAS,hdb3
# termtype: te
fxsks=32-46,48-62
dchan=47
echocanceller=mg2,32-46,48-62

# Span 3: TE4/0/3 "T4XXP (PCI) Card 0 Span 3"
span=3,3,0,CAS,hdb3
# termtype: te
fxsks=63-77,79-93
dchan=78
echocanceller=mg2,63-77,79-93

# Span 4: TE4/0/4 "T4XXP (PCI) Card 0 Span 4"
span=4,4,0,CAS,hdb3
# termtype: te
fxsks=94-108,110-124
dchan=109
echocanceller=mg2,94-108,110-124

# Span 5: WCT1/0 "Wildcard TE121 Card 0"
span=5,5,0,CAS,hdb3
# termtype: te
fxsks=125-139,141-155
dchan=140
echocanceller=mg2,125-139,141-155

# Global data

loadzone        = us
defaultzone     = us
```

When I am start my dahdi 4 port card only is working. Single port card is not working. What is the reason. Is there any mistake in the above configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Message about ethernet is not revalent. Card can work as network connection.

Try

> dahdi_genconfig

it will create new config based on your cards.

Check output of

> dahdi_cfg -vvvv

to see errors

Answer (score 0):

The message about the card being an ethernet controller is not revalent to you. The message at a very low level is technically accurate. Those cards can handle T1 and ISDN connections. In some very specific situations, users will split a T1 in to voice and data. This was more common in days gone by. It is less common these days. It is also just not really an elegant solution either, but that's another story. Your Digium card can and will work fine for you. Do complete your configuration of the card according to the provisioning sheet you got from your telco and you ought to be off and running. If not, let me know, and I can help get you the rest of the way there.